# Return the index of the an object passing two conditions

Tags: coffeescript, underscore.js

I am using underscore js and I have an array of objects.

```
[{"a":"j1","b":1,"c":1,"life":1},{"a":"j2","b":5,"c":7,"life":5},{"a":"j3","b":9,"c":0,"life":9},{"a":"j4","b":4,"c":1,"life":4}]
```

I want to get the index of the the object whose property value is minimum at `b` and `c`. I only wanted to get 1 of each object in case there are object sharing the same `b` and `c`

I have these recursive function

```
groupByMulti: (obj, values, context) -> 
  if (!values.length)
      return obj;
  byFirst = _.groupBy(obj, values[0], context)
  rest = values.slice(1)
  for i in byFirst
    byFirst[i] = groupByMulti(byFirst[i], rest, context)
  return byFirst
```

Comment: So what would your function return in this example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Filter function to return an array with items that pass the provided functions test.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter